# How to move a serializer.data into custom Instance (field) with Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django-rest-framework

I am able to get the JSON result below using django-rest-framework.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "fieldA": 1,
    "fieldB": 100
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "fieldA": 2,
    "fieldB": 101
 },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "fieldA": 1,
    "fieldB": 101
 }
```

I just want to change the structure to this.

```
{
    "typeA":      
       {
         "id": 1,
         "fieldA": 1,
         "fieldB": 100
       }
 },
 {
    "typeB":      
       {
         "id": 2,
         "fieldA": 2,
         "fieldB": 100,
       },
       {
         "id": 3,
         "fieldA": 1,
         "fieldB": 101,
       }
 }
```

`typeA` includes objects where `fieldB == 100` and `typeB` includes objects where `fieldB == 101`.

I can handle the results using like `Objects.filter()` at `get_query_set()` in views.py. So you don't need to care about it.

**The key of my question is how I can insert my customized field name and move the results to its child level.** Currently, I guess the solution would be related to `create()` and `update()` functions from building a serializer. Please give any tips or hints.

Here's my **model.py** for more information.

```
class Results(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.ForeignKey(Model)
    fieldB = models.ForeignKey(EplTeams, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class ResultsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResultSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        typeA = Results.objects.filter( fieldB=100 )
        typeB = Results.objects.filter( fieldB=101 )
        queryset = list( itertools.chain(typeA, typeB) )

        return queryset
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `ListSerializer`

In your serializers.py:

```
class CustomListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        resdata = []
        data1 = data.filter(fieldB=100)
        data2 = data.filter(fieldB=101)
        resdata.append({'typeA': super(CustomListSerializer, self).to_representation(data1)})
        resdata.append({'typeB': super(CustomListSerializer, self).to_representation(data2)})
        return resdata

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Results
        list_serializer_class = CustomListSerializer
```

Learn more about ListSerializer [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer)

Comment: many thanks to you. Your code works almostly except `data.filter()`. when I used `data.filter(fieldB=100)` or `data.filter(data.fieldB=100)` or `data.filter(data['fieldB']=100)`, my AWS server returns 500 internal server error. So I confirmed that data type is an object. I guess it is kind of JSON Object. To solve this problem, I replace `data.filter(fieldB=100)` with `[ d for d in data if d.fieldB==100]`, then it seems to work perfectly.  BUT, I'm still curious about why I can't `data.filter()`. For your reference, I am using Python 2.7x.

Comment: I am adding more information. I printed out `data` on server log. It is like `[<Results: Results object>, <Results: Results object>, <Results: Results object> ...]`. so I can't adapt `data.objects.filter()`, either.